# Azure WebAPP HTTP Request Duration

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring

I have a WebApp and want to monitor how long API calls take to execute? Is there a way I can set up app insights or something to log the duration of all HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Application Insight` configured you should find it in `Performance` tab

[image]

[image]

Comment: @NeilHartley if this answer is helpful for you please consider accepting it.

Comment: @NeilHartley does it help you solve your issue? Please if yes, consider accepting the answer.